# Parsing Attribute values of XML into a CSV using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have the below xml as a part of a main xml.  was able to extract this into a string, now I want to parse the below xml and get the values of the Attribute names PersonN , VerifiedHuman , CurrAddrBlockIndex into a seperate csv file
Please let me know how to overcome this issue ?

**XML I am trying to parse :**

```
<InterConnectResponse>
  <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  <ConsumerSubjects>
    <ConsumerSubject subjectIdentifier="Primary">
      <DataSourceResponses>
      <RiskViewProducts>
          <RiskViewAttribResponse>
          <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                  <Name>PersonN</Name>
                  <Value>3</Value>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute>
                  <Name>VerifiedHuman</Name>
                  <Value>2</Value>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute>
                  <Name>CurrAddrBlockIndex</Name>
                  <Value>0.61</Value>
                </Attribute>
         </Attributes>
         </RiskViewAttribResponse>
     </RiskViewProducts>
     </DataSourceResponses>
    </ConsumerSubject>
  </ConsumerSubjects>
</InterConnectResponse>
```

**Expected Output file :**

```
3, 2, 0.61
```

**I tried this but did not succeed**

```
  StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();   
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(value)))
            {

                reader.ReadToFollowing("PersonN");
                string LNREF72 = reader.Value;
                output.AppendLine(LNREF72);
                reader.ReadToFollowing("VerifiedHuman");
                string VerifiedHuman = reader.Value;
                output.AppendLine(", " + VerifiedHuman);
                reader.ReadToFollowing("CurrAddrBlockIndex");
                string CurrAddrBlockIndex = reader.Value;
                output.AppendLine(", " + CurrAddrBlockIndex);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the way I would do it but if you are going to use XmlReader this would be the way to do what you want.

Please look into XmlDocument or one of a dozen other way to parse XML that is better than XmlReader.

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(value)))
{
    bool isValue = false;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Value")
        {
            isValue = true;
        }

        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text && isValue)
        {
            output.AppendLine((output.Length == 0 ? "" : ", ") + reader.Value);
            isValue = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting  the error   `SystemArgumentException : Illegal Characters in Path`  at line :  ` using (XmlReader read = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(str3)))`

Comment: I do not know the value of str3 so unless you post what that value is not much I can comment on.

Comment: Oops sorry  !  str3 is the xml I posted

Comment: StreamReader takes a path to the xml file.  IE "C:\test.xml"

Comment: Ohh I dont have a physical path to xml... This xml I posted is extracted from a bigger XML using this :

`foreach (XElement descendant in xdocument.Descendants("EquifaxInterconnectAttributes"))
                            {
                                string str3 = descendant.Value;`

Comment: Change StreamReader to StringReader

Comment: That actually worked ! any idea how to save the result as a csv file on drive?

Comment: File.WriteAllText("C:\\test.csv", output.ToString());